# How do prove that matrix $A^p$ is invertible given that A is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A is invertible, show that $A^p$ is invertible for all integers $p > 1$.  $A^{-p}$ := $( A^p )^{-1}$

I'm confused as to how to approach a problem like this. How would you prove that $A^p$ is invertible?

Comment: Can you find a matrix $B$ such that $A^pB=BA^p=1$?

Comment: Try induction ?

Comment: Have you learned that the determinant of a product is the product of determinants?

Comment: Do you know what it means for a matrix to be invertible?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:lets see what happens if $p=3$.

$(A^3)(A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1})=AAAA^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}=I$ Similarly we observe that $(A^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1})A^3=I$ This is to say $A^3$ is invertible.